# How to export a IDW raster while keeping the search radius data

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, export, inverse-distance-weighted

I want to export my IDW rasters that I made in ArcGIS to QGIS, however when I export my raster, the values are there but are no longer displayed. They are stored within each cell and are not incorporated in a IDW search radius.

How is it possible to make sure that I can create the same image as my original.

Original

[image]
Export version
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is only due to the symbology, your original raster is symbolized with a classified method and bilinear interpolation resampling. I don't know what's used to symbolize the second one, maybe just pixel values or classified with nearest neighbor resampling. You can manage this in ArcGIS using the Symbology and Display tabs of the layer properties. I don't know QGIS and its options for symbology.